# No implementation found for method init on channel flutter.io/videoPlayer video_player 0.10.8+1 after cresting my own Custom method channel

Tags: flutter, kotlin

> E/flutter ( 8743): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
>   for method init on channel flutter.io/videoPlayer) E/flutter ( 8743):
>   MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7) E/flutter (
>   8743): E/flutter ( 8743): #1 MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>   (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)

My flutter doctor -version

> [✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.16.4-pre.18, on Mac OS X 10.15.3
>   19D76, locale en-GB) • Flutter version 1.16.4-pre.18 at
>   /Users/olanrewaju/Dev/flutter • Framework revision c8efcb6 (6 days
>   ago), 2020-03-27 22:31:01 -0700 • Engine revision 3ee9e3d378 • Dart
>   version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.17.0 1402e8e1a4)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2) • Android SDK at /Users/olanrewaju/Library/Android/sdk
>   • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native
>   profiling support) • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2 • Java
>   binary at: /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java • Java version
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211) • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1) • Xcode at
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer • Xcode 11.3.1, Build
>   version 11C504 • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.6) • Android Studio at
>   /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents • Flutter plugin version
>   44.0.2 • Dart plugin version 192.7761 • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
>
> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1) • IntelliJ at
>   /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app • Flutter plugin version 34.0.4 • Dart
>   plugin version 191.6183.88
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1) • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio
>   Code.app/Contents • Flutter extension version 3.8.1
>
> [!] Connected device ! No devices available

You can reproduce the error by

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_30MB.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Environment
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import java.io.File

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

        private val CHANNEL = "com.test/test"
    private val PERMISSION = 8798798


    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler { call: MethodCall?, result: MethodChannel.Result? ->
                    if (call?.method == "testAction") {

                        result?.success("Test")
                    } else {
                        result?.notImplemented()
                    }

                }
    }


}
```

add   `video_player: ^0.10.8+1` to dependencies.

Video player works if I don't have any method channel.